# Is it possible to trigger a DOM event manually with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I needed to trigger a `keyup` event manually. I could only find implementations that involved jQuery. Is there any way to do it with plain JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, google "diapatch event mdn".

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
input.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', {'key':'y'}));
```

[Dispatch Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)

Answer (score 0):

You can see this > https://www.cnblogs.com/xiaozhuyuan/p/8296827.html you can find the answer for your problem